# Show $\sum_{k = 1} ^n \frac{(k - 1)n^2}{n(n - k + 1)^2} = O(n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, asymptotics, alternative-proof

I am trying to show $\sum_{k = 1} ^n \frac{(k - 1)n^2}{n(n - k + 1)^2} = O(n^2)$. This should be easy enough, but I am stuck and can't see how to finish it off.

**My solution so far**:
This is the same as showing $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(k - 1)}{n(n - k + 1)^2} \leq C$ for some $C > 0$ when $n$ is sufficiently large. Hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(k - 1)}{n(n - k + 1)^2} &= \sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{j}{n(n - j)^2} \\
&= \sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{j}{n(j - n)^2} \\
&= \sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{j}{n(j^2 - 2jn + n^2)} \\
&= \sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{1}{n(j - 2n + \frac{n^2}{j})}.
\end{align*}
Now the last term resembles $\sum_{j = 1} ^n \frac{1}{j}$ the harmonic series, which is $O(\log n)$. How could I incorporate this fact with the calculation? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track: note that by letting $i=n-j$ we find
$$\sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{j}{n(n-j)^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{n-i}{i^2}=\sum_{i = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i^2}- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i}=O(1)+\frac{O(\ln(n))}{n}=O(1).$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you explain the second to last step a bit more? I am new to big $O$ notations and I am not so familiar with the operations: How does one understand the notation $\sum_{j = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i^2}$, when the iteration is on $j$ and how do I show it is $O(1)$? Is this some subsequence rule that I might've forgotten?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to change the index. $\sum_{i = 1} ^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i^2}=O(1)$ because the series is convergent. Recall that $O(1)$ means bounded.