# Follow up question-Rule of Big $O$ Notation and Little $O$ notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, asymptotics

This is a follow up question from my previous post: [Show $\sum_{k = 1} ^n \frac{(k - 1)n^2}{n(n - k + 1)^2} = O(n^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739386/show-sum-k-1-n-frack-1n2nn-k-12-on2/4739389?noredirect=1#comment10050422_4739389). I now understand the sum on the left is $O(n^2)$. Let me call the sum $f(n)$ for convenience.

**It is now claimed** in the proofs that I am reading claims $\frac{f(n)}{n^2 \log^2 n} = o(\frac{1}{\log^2 n})$. **However, I am not sure if I see this is true**

This is essentially saying
$$
\lim_n \frac{f(n)}{n^2 \log^2 n} \log^2 n = \lim_n \frac{f(n)}{n^2} = 0.
$$
The only information that we have is $\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ is upper bounded when $n \to \infty$. **How could we conclude the claim?**

Answer (score 0):

f(n) is between n^2 and pi^2/6 n^2, so your function is between 1 / log^2 n and (pi^2/6) / log^2 n. So it’s not little-o but both big-O and $\theta (1 / log^2 n)$